# The type 'ArrayConstructor' does not define the field, constructor or member 'map'

Tags: .net, f#

Trying to do a simple Array map in F#. I have hundreds of these in my code but it doesn't seem to be working in this module.

Inside a function, I have this binding

```
    let roomLinkList : string[] = 
        getRoomList currentVenue //room[]
        |> Array.map convertRoomToLink
```

Where

```
//room -> string
let convertRoomListToLinks (room:room) = "<a>"+room.name+"</a>"
```

IDE throws the error `The type 'ArrayConstructor' does not define the field, constructor or member 'map'.`.

Am I missing a reference or something?

I tried List.map too for giggles, that was recognized but incorrect function signature of course.

Answer (score 1):

And I had Fable.Core.JS for some reason (this is not a Fable project) included and it was using their Array module.